# Ionicpopup automatic cursor gores off when selected once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic popup in my code in which i have created a directive to make the automatic cursor to focus the input box.It is working fine when the popup is opened for the first time but the cursor is not getting focused to the input box again when i close the popup and open it again can anyone tell me why it occurs.

Code:

```
$scope.data = {};
  var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<input focus-me type="text" ng-model="data.expensetype" limit-char limit="15">',
    title: $translate.instant('{{"pentercoconuttype_message" | translate}}'),
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [
     { text: $translate.instant('{{"pcancel_message" | translate}}') },
      {
        text: $translate.instant('{{"psave_message" | translate}}'),
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function (e) {
          if (!$scope.data.expensetype) {
            //don't allow the user to close unless he enters producttype
            e.preventDefault();

          } else {
            addExpenseCategory();
            return $scope.data.expensetype;
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  });
  myPopup.then(function (res) {
    $log.log('Tapped!', res);
    myPopup.close();
  });
```

Directive:

```
.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
return {
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

  $timeout(function() {
    element[0].focus(); 
  });
}
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 150ms to the $timeout to make sure the view is completely rendered.

```
.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
return {
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

$timeout(function() {
  element[0].focus(); 
 }, 150);
}
};
});
```